# Download Email Attachments via Simulataneous Cron Jobs -- Race Condition

Tags: php, multithreading, codeigniter, cron

I need a cron job to check email accounts and download certain attachments. This cron job will be running every minute. My problem is that when the first script is downloading email attachments, a second (or third or fourth ...) script will most likley be running alongside the previously executed script. The problem is that I am not sure what is the best way to prevent subsequent scripts from trying to download the email attachments that the previous scripts have downloaded (or is currently downloading).

Other details:

- Using CodeIgniter
- Using Zend Mail library to access emails and download attachments
- Email is probably going to be POP3

I'm wondering if I can use "message-id" header somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just prevent concurrent cron scripts from running by using a lock file. You probably don't want concurrent scripts downloading the attachments, you will have nasty race conditions.

Works like this:

starter.sh

- Checks if the lock file exists, if it does, exit immediately.
- If it does not, it creates a lock file and starts the main.php script.
- After main.php completes, it deletes the lock file.
- This way if main.php crashes or throws an exception, the lock file is deleted and it is able to restart the next minute.

main.php

- does the actual downloading.

**Edit**

I see. You then need a more complex setup. single threaded script that reads the from, subject and datetime, and sticks them in a queue (a db table is perfect for this). It should work as I explained above. Secondly you have a pool of php processes that read the db table and downloads attachments based of the data in the table.

Since they are working with a thread safe data structure (the database) they can set a flag on each row that says downloading/downloaded.

They just working a loop with a sql select at the top (select top 1 not downloaded/downloading messages). You will need something to handle crashes and restart php processes, but that is the jist of it.

Comment: Multiple scripts running at the same time is actually ideal. I'm trying to simulate multi-threading. I'm dealing with thousands of email attachments per hour.